# How to click a button multiple times and change modes in an android app

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I am new to Android Development. I need to build a temperature converter app which would convert Celcius to Farenheit and Farenheit to Celcius. I have used an editText for user input. There are two buttons. One button is to convert the input and the other one is the mode button which would toggle between the two modes of conversion. When I launch the app the mode is in celcius to farenheit by default. By clicking on mode button I can change the mode to farenheit to celcius scale. The problem is that when I again click on the mode button it does not return to the celcius to farenheit conversion mode. I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me in this regard?

I have set the function getset() for the convert button and function mode() for the mode button.

```
fun getSet(view: View)
{
    val convert = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    convert.setOnClickListener {
        if(editText.length()==0)
        {
            editText.setError("Enter a Value")
        }
        else
        {
            val editxt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
            val msg = editxt.text.toString()
            val txtview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {
                val cel = msg.toDouble()
                val far =  (cel*1.8)+32
                    text = "Result: " + far.toString()
                }
            }
        }
  }
  fun mode(view: View)
  {
    val convert = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    val heading = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
            val caption =  "Farenheit to Celcius"
            text = caption
        }
    convert.setOnClickListener {
        if(editText.length()==0)
        {
                editText.setError("Enter a Value")
        }
        else
        {
            val editxt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
            val msg = editxt.text.toString()
            val txtview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {
                    val far = msg.toDouble()
                    val cel =  (far-32)*0.5555555556
                    text = "Result: " + cel.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the "mode" in a global variable.
create a global variable

```
var isModeCelsius: Boolean = true
```

Now inside your onCreate() method in your activity, under the setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name) line enter the below code.

```
//Initialize edittext and button
    val convert = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    val heading = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    val modeButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.id_of_button)
    val editxt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
    val showResultTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)
    //You only need to assign the click listener once
    modeButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (isModeCelsius) {
            isModeCelsius = false
        } else {
            isModeCelsius = true
        }

        //Or you can simply use
        //isModeCelsius=!isModeCelsius
    }
    convert.setOnClickListener {
        val msg = editxt.text.toString()
        if(isModeCelsius){
            val far = msg.toDouble()
            val cel =  (far-32)*0.5555555556
            showResultTextView.text = "Result: " + cel.toString()
        }else{
            val cel = msg.toDouble()
            val far =  (cel*1.8)+32
            showResultTextView.text = "Result: " + far.toString()
        }
    }
```